# How to fetch the column number in c++?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, data-structures

I want to know the column number when a heading is given.

For example for `S    Mac   Bonded State       SIS  Qos(DS-US)   CPE  MAC address     IP Address`

Column 1 is `S`, 2 is `Mac`, 3 is `Bonded`, 4 is `State`, 5 is `SIS`, 6 is `Qos(DS-US)`, 7 is `CPE`, 8 is `MAC address` and 9 is `IP Address`

The problem is, if the split based on space`" "`, MAC and address will be considered as different columns which is not correct.

First 3 lines of the file I am parsing

```
S/C/CH-S/CG/CH    Mac   Bonded State       SIS  Qos(DS-US)   CPE  MAC address     IP Address
12/0/18-1/0/0     1      4x4   Operational 3.0   120M/12M      0  000f.c22a.7014  10.135.148.24
12/0/0-1/0/4      1      4x4   Operational 3.0   120M/12M      0  1121.10fc.3993  10.135.148.50
12/0/8-1/0/0      1      4x4   Operational 3.0   120M/12M      0  1121.81fc.1234  10.135.148.43
```

The columns are always aligned in the same position, so this can be a solution  but I dont know how to get the positions.

Whats is the best way to solve the problem?

Comment: Could there be tabs between fields which you are not seeing?

Comment: Could you post the first 3-4 lines of the file you want to parse ? And please post it also to http://pastebin.com/ so we can see the file verbatim.

Comment: No, there is not tab fields.

Comment: If the columns start at fixed positions, you just can hard code them.

Comment: But I dont know the positions while running the program. It might change dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You could use another deliminator to split the columns. eg in stead of a space (`" "`) you could use a comma (`","`) or a hyphen (`"-"`). I'd suggest using something that likely won't be used elsewhere in the file to avoid any bugs.

Comment: I cannot change the data, I can just parse it

Comment: perhaps you could use some if statements and temp variables to check for certain headings, assuming you know in advance what the headings are going to be. Say, if the first temp input var gives you `MAC` and the next temp input var gives you `Address` then you group them into one column. It's not an elegant fix but it could work.

Comment: But this wont work if I need to know the column number of IP Address because it will count 2 columns for MAC address. 
This will work only if i know all the headings prior.

Comment: Yes you'd need some info about the headings prior. I was thinking something like:
`if(( temp1 == "MAC" ) && ( temp2 == "Address" )){
columnNumber++;
//Add it to an array or something?
}`
In this way you'd parse the first line looking for pairs and put the headings (singles and pairs) into an array or something where their column numbers are clearly defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use `boost::algorithm::split_regex`:

```
std::vector<std::string> result;
std::string str = "S    Mac   Bonded State       SIS  Qos(DS-US)   CPE  MAC address"
boost::algorithm::split_regex( result, str, regex( "  " ) ) ;
```

If you want to accept more than one white spaces as delimeter, just use regex `"\s{2,}"`

Comment: I cannot use 2 spaces as some columns are just separated by single space

Comment: In that case, there is no way to distinguish if a single space is a column separator or a part of a column name. Consider changing separators as other suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the split based on column positions.

The first item starts at column 1 and ends at column 18, the second item starts at column 19 and ends at column 25 etc.

Do the split in two phases:

**Phase 1:**

Split the line based on column positions which will give you:

- `"12/0/18-1/0/0     "`
- `"1      "`
- `"4x4   "`
- `"Operational "`
- `"3.0   "`
- `"120M/12M      "`
- `"0  "`
- `"000f.c22a.7014"`
- `"10.135.148.24"`

**Phase 2:**

Strip trailing spaces which will result in:

- `"12/0/18-1/0/0"`
- `"1"`
- `"4x4"`
- etc.

Comment: How to derive the positions?

Comment: @user2314946 the positions are fixed. Read the second paragraph of my answer: _The first item starts at column 1 and ends at column 18, the second item starts at column 19 and ends at column 25 etc._